# php push notification for android giving xml error

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I am trying to send the push notification from php to android users. Using following code

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
        define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'access_key');
        $registrationIds = array( "reg_id" );
        // prep the bundle
        $msg = array
        (
            'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
            'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
            'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
            'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
            'vibrate'   => 1,
            'sound'     => 1,
            'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
            'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
        );
        $fields = array
        (
            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
            'data'          => $msg
        );

        $headers = array
        (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        echo $result;
?>
```

But getting following response

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I did some R&D, but everyone are getting error in json, but I am getting in xml format. I used postman for this. I also directly checked from browser by hitting the url for this script, but still returning the same error.

```
Unauthorized

Error 401
```

I checked on my local system and on server both, but same error.

Comment: Did you use the correct key? I have used the same code. So it's working for sure.

Comment: @driftking9987, android guys says that they have given correct key. is there any way to check if key is correct ?

Comment: I just checked after deleting one char from the key, I too got the same unauthorized 401 error. I'll say the key is wrong. Ask them to recheck.

Comment: Are you sure `API_ACCESS_KEY` is defined and it has the right value?

Comment: thanks to all, the key was wrong from the mobile team. whom should i mark as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

First Check you have missed this line in your curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

and check your api key is valid or not.. Your function will work fine hopefully.

Comment: @Purushottam zende if you want to check api key is correct or not you can create your own api key for testing, go to this [link](https://console.developers.google.com/) create a project then create an api key for gcm and put it in your code if it works then your first api key was not valid.